# How do I change the value of a header for each request inside a datasource loop?

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I have a header called *RequestID* that has a value of a UUID I generated in the groovy script below:

```
import static java.util.UUID.randomUUID
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap  

def uuid = randomUUID() as String
def headers = new StringToStringMap()

headers.put("RequestID", uuid)
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Get Username").testRequest.setRequestHeaders(headers)
```

I also have a REST request named "Get Username" that is called multiple times via a datasource loop. My groovy script seems to only be generating one UUID for the entirety of the loop and not a new UUID for each hit. Am I missing something in my script or is the order of the steps wrong? I'm also using a grid in my datasource step called *SSN* to feed data into the request.

Here is the order of my steps in SOAPUI:

- SSN
- Groovy Script
- Get Username,
- DataSource Loop (Datasource step: SSN, Target step: Get Username)

Essentially every time a new request is sent, there should be a new requestid. If that makes sense.

Comment: Your script seemed ok. does not seem to be an issue. It will keep  generating new uuid in each loop. Isn't it?

Comment: @Rao, i'm not entirely sure. Is there a way to slow down the execution of a testcase in soapui to check? Because according to some logging it looks like it's using the same uuid for the duration of the datasource loop

Comment: If you are using readyapi1.9, there is debugging feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the test reaches the DataSource Loop it gets new data from the DataSource and executes the target test step (in your case - Get Username). So it executes the Groovy script only once.

Change the Target test step in the DataSource Loop to the Groovy Script test step.